# Infinispan Server Cluster - define member IP addresses

Tags: infinispan

I tried to replace our memcached servers with Infinispan Server to get replication/distribution features for our services.

Using the `clustered-memcached.xml` example configuration I can easily run Infinispan Servers on multiple hosts, but the problem is that the auto discovery/multicast feature will find all Infinispan Server instances on the whole network, meaning it will join all our stages (test, qa, production) together to a single cluster ... which is obviously not what anybody wants.

Is there an example on how I can define cluster members by IP/port without any UDP multicast discovery magic? The documentation has zero content about isolating clusters ... and in general lacks of useful xml examples.

Comment: Hello, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45719003/infinispan-cluster-of-a-predefined-set-of-ip-addresses

Comment: @Diego yes I already tried that providing only the IPs of the desired cluster members but still all instances find each other even though I haven't configured their IP addresses

Comment: I removed my answer from that post because it was related to embedded mode. I decided to post the answer here. Tks Radim Vansa

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is configure the `initial_hosts` adding what are the IP addresses. In this example, we are using `192.168.1.2[7600],192.168.1.3[7600]`

The following is a partial stack configuration

```xml
    <stack name="tcp">
        <transport type="TCP" socket-binding="jgroups-tcp"/>
        <protocol type="TCPPING">
            <property name="initial_hosts">192.168.1.2[7600],192.168.1.3[7600]</property>
            <property name="num_initial_members">2</property>
            <property name="port_range">0</property>
            <property name="timeout">2000</property>
        </protocol>
        .......
    </stack>
```

Once you have configured the `initial_hosts`, you need to change what will be the `stacks` when the server starts.

1) You can replace `${jboss.default.jgroups.stack:udp}` with `tcp`

OR

2) Start the server with `./standalone.sh -c clustered.xml -Djboss.default.jgroups.stack=tcp`

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:infinispan:server:jgroups:9.4">
  <channels default="cluster">
    <channel name="cluster"/>
  </channels>
  <stacks default="${jboss.default.jgroups.stack:udp}">
    ...
  </stacks>
</subsystem>
```

Comment: if I run a third instance on 192.168.1.99 without configuring anything related to the 2 other instances, the 3rd instance automagically joins the cluster after 2-5 minutes (not on start but shortly after) (I am observing this behaviour in 3 vagrant boxes and I haven't found a way to build independent and isolated clusters ... all instances sooner or later find each other and join together)

Comment: also there is no property named "cluster" for transport element (error in log)

Comment: I removed the wrong configuration. About Vagrant boxes and Cluster you should create another question on StackOverflow because they are not related. You should try to configure Jgroups with "PING with a different mcast address for each cluster" OR "DNS_PING + headless service"

Comment: Cluster1: <transport type="UDP" socket-binding="jgroups-udp"><property name="mcast_addr">228.10.10.1</property></transport> Cluster2: <transport type="UDP" socket-binding="jgroups-udp"><property name="mcast_addr">228.10.10.2</property></transport> As I said, a new question will be better because another user would like to setup Vagrant